# switch between page object api and main nightwatch api

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am using the page object model with nightwatch for my tests. Having difficulty interacting with an element so was forced to execute some jquery. Execute is not part of the subset of commands that are available in the page object api, so in order to use it, I must call the full nightwatch command api. (see more regarding this at https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Page-Object-API) My question is how do I return to the page object api after my execute statement.

My page object is like this:

```
elements: {
  nameInput: 'input[name="name"]',
  billingEmail: 'input[name="billingEmail"]',
  licenseNumber: 'input[name="licenses.total"]',
  licensePrice: 'input[name="subscription.price"]',
  hardwareModel: 'input[name="model"]',
  hardwareQuantity: 'input[name="quantity"]',
  hardwarePrice: 'input[name="price"]',
  customerEmail: 'input[name="customerEmail"]',
  createButton: 'button[name="createAccount"]',
  cancelButton: 'button[name="cancel"]',
},


inputClientDetails (name, email) {
    this
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 10000)
      .setValue('@nameInput', name)
      .setValue('@billingEmail', email)
      .setValue('@licenseNumber', '10')
      .setValue('@licensePrice', '9.99')
      .api.execute(function () {
          $('.datepicker--wrapper').find('input[type=text]').val('2017-08-30').trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 40}));
      })
      .setValue('@hardwareModel', 'Test model')
      .setValue('@hardwarePrice', '9.99')
      .setValue('@hardwareQuantity', '10')
      .setValue('@customerEmail', email)
      .click('@createButton')
    return this.api;
},
```

When I run my test I get the error:
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "@hardwareModel" using: css selector

When I don't have the execute statement in the page object there is no issue. So is it possible to return to the page object api after accessing the main nightwatch api? I tried putting a return statement in the function but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you call `.api.whatever()`,
 the function you call after by chaining is using the `.api` as well (which is the browser).

A better way to do it is to split your function in two parts without chaining the whole thing.

```
inputClientDetails (name, email) {
var client=this.api;
this
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 10000)
  .setValue('@nameInput', name)
  .setValue('@billingEmail', email)
  .setValue('@licenseNumber', '10')
  .setValue('@licensePrice', '9.99')
//now use client-browser
client.execute(function () {
      $('.datepicker--wrapper').find('input[type=text]').val('2017-08-30').trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 40}));
  })
//Now back to page object
this.setValue('@hardwareModel', 'Test model')
  .setValue('@hardwarePrice', '9.99')
  .setValue('@hardwareQuantity', '10')
  .setValue('@customerEmail', email)
  .click('@createButton')
return this.api;
//either this.api or this doesn't matter, but this.api if you still have other chained function based on browser.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for this issue:

1st : `api` will return `this.api` instead of `this` page-object so we are only able to call this page object via `page`

```
inputClientDetails (name, email) {
this
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 10000)
  .setValue('@nameInput', name)
  .setValue('@billingEmail', email)
  .setValue('@licenseNumber', '10')
  .setValue('@licensePrice', '9.99')
  .api.execute(function () {
      $('.datepicker--wrapper').find('input[type=text]').val('2017-08-30').trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 40}));
  })
  .page.yourPage().setValue('@hardwareModel', 'Test model') 
  .page.yourPage().setValue('@hardwarePrice', '9.99')
  .page.yourPage().setValue('@hardwareQuantity', '10')
  .page.yourPage().setValue('@customerEmail', email)
  .page.yourPage().click('@createButton')
return this.api;
```

},

2nd : your can split your function, smaller function should return `this` page object instead `this.api`

```
inputClientDetails (name, email) {
    this
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 10000)
      .setValue('@nameInput', name)
      .setValue('@billingEmail', email)
      .setValue('@licenseNumber', '10')
      .setValue('@licensePrice', '9.99')
      .callExecute()
      .setValue('@hardwareModel', 'Test model')
      .setValue('@hardwarePrice', '9.99')
      .setValue('@hardwareQuantity', '10')
      .setValue('@customerEmail', email)
      .click('@createButton')
    return this.api;
},

callExecute(){
      this.api.execute(function () {
          $('.datepicker--wrapper').find('input[type=text]').val('2017-08-30').trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: 40}));
      });
     return this;
}
```

Comment: I went with the solution from Raymond above but thanks for taking the time to submit an answer Bao!